# How to check if the variable value in AWK script is null or empty?

Tags: unix, awk

1. I am using **AWK** script to process some logs.
2. At one place I need to check if the variable value is **null** or **empty** to make some decision.

Any Idea how to achieve the same?

```
awk '

{
    {
       split($i, keyVal, "@")
       key=keyVal[1];
       val=keyVal[2];
       if(val ~ /^ *$/)
       val="Y";

    }

}

' File
```

I have tried with

```
1) if(val == "")

2) if(val ~ /^ *$/)
```

not working in both cases.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: your second evaluation would only equate to true if the string had at least one space and only a space character, for that you could have used `if(val ~ /^(\s*)?$/)` 
\s matches all space type characters (tab, space, null, newline etc), the ? makes it lazy so it'll match if the string is completely empty too

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The comparison with `""` should have worked, so that's a bit odd

As one more alternative, you could use the `length()` function, if zero, your variable is null/empty. E.g.,

```
if (length(val) == 0)
```

Also, perhaps the built-in variable `NF` (number of fields) could come in handy? Since we don't have access to your input data it's hard to say though, but another possibility.

Comment: Watch out, `length(val)` may not be portable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075845/how-to-check-if-awk-array-is-empty#comment29910443_20075924

Comment: @ericek111 : yeah it's "not portable" in the sense if someone is still writing for solaris `awk` from 15 years ago… there actually *is* a safe-and-efficient way to measure `array` length without wasting time counting one at a time, while auto-detecting `awk`s that require the slow approach, and runs that branch instead.

Answer (score 23):

You can directly use the variable without comparison, an empty/null/zero value is considered `false`, everything else is `true`.

See here :

```
# setting default tag if not provided
if (! tag) {
        tag="default-tag"
}
```

So this script will have the variable `tag` with the value `default-tag` except if the user call it like this :

```
$ awk -v tag=custom-tag -f script.awk targetFile
```

This is true as of :
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)

Answer (score 15):

It works just fine for me

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{if(val==""){print "null or empty"}}'
null or empty
```

You can't differentiate between variable being empty and null, when you access "unset" variable, awk just initializes it with default value(here it is `""` - empty string). You can use some sort of workaround, for example, setting `val_accessed` variable to `0` and then to `1` when you access it. Or more simple approach(somewhat "hackish") setting val to `"unitialized"`(or to some other value which can't appear when running your program).

PS: your script looks strange for me, what are the nested brackets for?

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally discovered this less-used function specific in `gawk` that could help differentiate :

```
****** gawk-only ******

BEGIN {
    $0 = "abc"

    print NF, $0

    test_function()
    test_function($(NF + 1))

    test_function("")
    test_function($0)
}
function test_function(_) { print typeof(_) }

1 abc

untyped
unassigned

string
string
```

So it seems, for `non-numeric-like` data :

```
  absolutely no input to function at all         :    untyped
  non-existent or empty field,      including $0 : unassigned
  any non-numeric-appearing string, including "" :     string
```

Here's the chaotic part - `numeric` data :

- strangely enough, for absolutely identical input, only differing between using `$0` vs. `$1` in function call, you frequently get a different value for `typeof()`
- even a combination of both leading and trailing spaces doesn't prevent `gawk` from identifying it as `strnum`

```
[123]:NF:1
                 $0 =  number:123          $1 =  strnum:123           +$1 =  number:123
[ 456.33]:NF:1
                 $0 =  string: 456.33      $1 =  strnum:456.33        +$1 =  number:456.33000
[ 19683 ]:NF:1
                 $0 =  string: 19683       $1 =  strnum:19683         +$1 =  number:19683

[-20.08554]:NF:1
                 $0 =  number:-20.08554    $1 =  strnum:-20.08554     +$1 =  number:-20.08554
```

`+/- inf/nan` (same for all 4):

```
[-nan]:NF:1

                 $0 =  string:-nan         $1 =  strnum:-nan          +$1 =  number:-nan
```

this one is a string because it was made from `sprintf()` :

```
[0x10FFFF]:NF:1
               $0 = string:0x10FFFF $1 = string:0x10FFFF +$1 = number:0
```

using `-n / --non-decimal-data` flag, all stays same except

```
[0x10FFFF]:NF:1
               $0 = string:0x10FFFF $1 = strnum:0x10FFFF +$1 = number:1114111
```

Long story short, if you want your `gawk` function to be able to differentiate between

- empty-string input (`""`), versus
- actually no input at all

  - e.g. when original intention is to directly apply changes to `$0`

then `typeof(x) == "untyped"` seems to be the most reliable indicator.

It gets worse when null-string padding versus a non-empty string of all zeros ::

```
function   __(_) { return (!_) ":" (!+_)  }
function  ___(_) { return (_ == "")       }
function ____(_) { return (!_) ":" (!""_) }


     $0--->[           "000" ] | __(""$0)-->{ !(""$0) : !+(""$0) }-->[ 0:1 ] 
 ___($0)-->{ $0=="" }-->[ 0 ]  | ____($0)-->{ !   $0  :  (!""$0) }-->[ 1:1000 ]


     $0--->[              "" ] | __(""$0)-->{ !(""$0) : !+(""$0) }-->[ 1:1 ] 
 ___($0)-->{ $0=="" }-->[ 1 ]  | ____($0)-->{ !   $0  :  (!""$0) }-->[ 1:1 ]


     $0--->[      " -0.0 -0" ] | __(""$0)-->{ !(""$0) : !+(""$0) }-->[ 0:1 ] 
 ___($0)-->{ $0=="" }-->[ 0 ]  | ____($0)-->{ !   $0  :  (!""$0) }-->[ 0:1 -0.0 -0 ]


     $0--->[          " 0x5" ] | __(""$0)-->{ !(""$0) : !+(""$0) }-->[ 0:1 ] 
 ___($0)-->{ $0=="" }-->[ 0 ]  | ____($0)-->{ !   $0  :  (!""$0) }-->[ 0:1 0x5 ]
```