# how to check if awk array is empty

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am brand new to AWK and trying to determine if my array is empty or not so i can print a message if so. Typically i am use to length functions and can check like that, but it does not seem AWK has those. Here is my working code, i just want to print out a different message if there is nothing in the array after parsing all my data.

```
#add to array if condition is met
if ($2 == "SOURCE" && $4 == "RESTRICTED"){
    sourceAndRestricted[$3]++;
}
#print out array
for (var in sourceAndRestricted){
    printf "\t\t"var"\n" 
}
```

ive tried something like this and its not working. Suggestions?

```
for (var in sourceAndRestricted){
    if (var > 1){
        printf "\t\t"var"\n" 
    }
    else {
        print "NONE"
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep a counter in the for loop and check it after?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check it with `length()` function:

```
if ( length(sourceAndRestricted) > 0 ) {
    printf "\t\t"var"\n"
}
else
    print "NONE"
}
```

Comment: gawk 3.1.5 and newer only. I don't know about other awk:s.

Comment: @EtanReisner: It works for me with `--traditional` switch too, that teorically make it works without `GNU` extensions.

Comment: did not know there was a length function! Thank you very much, this worked!

Comment: It does appear to work with `--traditional` but does not work with `--posix` and the man page says it is gawk specific (and was added in 3.1.5). It also is not in mawk. I can't say more than that.

Comment: `length(array)` is considered an extension in gawk and I hear it works in OSX awk too but it's definitely not portable.

Comment: There is a downside to this: `gawk 'BEGIN{if(length(arr)==0) arr[1]=1}'` produces an error: `gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: attempt to use scalar 'arr' as an array`.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function isEmpty(arr, idx) {for (idx in arr) return 0; return 1}

BEGIN {
   map[3] = 27

   print isEmpty(map)

   delete map[3]

   print isEmpty(map)
}
$ awk -f tst.awk
0
1
```